# SSMS crashing when opening SSIS in SQL Job Agent

Tags: crash, ssms-2012

Using SQL Management Studio 2012,

[image]

When opening SQL Job Agent -> Open a job -> Wanting to edit a SQL Integration Services Package -> SSMS crashes and comes with this error message:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. (SqlManagerUI) ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (DTEParseMgd) BUTTONS: OK
```

And when debugging I get this message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x23627995 in Ssms.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x004640fc.
```

Could not find anything useful to resolve this issue so here I am...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (on win server 2012 with SQL2012 SP1). Solved by installing SQL server 2012 SP2.
I hope it will be helpful for you too.
DD